# WARN: Write to InfluxDB failed [[RequestTimedOutError]]

Tags: node.js, influxdb

```
WARN: Write to InfluxDB failed (attempt: 1). Error: 
at S.<anonymous> (/Users/sathish/Documents/sample/raviAPI/node_modules/core-js/internals/wrap-error-constructor-with-cause.js:37:62)
at new super (/Users/sathish/Documents/sample/raviAPI/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.error.cause.js:28:43)
at new S (/Users/sathish/Documents/sample/raviAPI/node_modules/@influxdata/influxdb-client/src/errors.ts:163:5)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/sathish/Documents/sample/raviAPI/node_modules/@influxdata/influxdb-client/src/impl/node/NodeHttpTransport.ts:346:23)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:314:20)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
at Socket.emitRequestTimeout (_http_client.js:715:9)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:483:8)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

name: 'RequestTimedOutError',
message: 'Request timed out'

I am facing this issue while writing data for each second in influxdb.
This is the influxdb client i am using from nodejs **@influxdata/influxdb-client**

Comment: This sounds like a networking issue, not necessarily a nodejs app or influxdb setup issue, but it isn't enough to go on. Could you share some more details of your setup? Where is the InfluxDB server located? Is it accessible from where you're running your node app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to answer this if you would post some of the code here.

looks like classing http request timeout
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-js/blob/558b3b4f6a5fd1e94c1579bd894cb0ce5e126368/packages/core/src/impl/node/NodeHttpTransport.ts#L345

which comes from regular nodejs http.IncomingMessage

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-js/blob/558b3b4f6a5fd1e94c1579bd894cb0ce5e126368/packages/core/src/impl/node/NodeHttpTransport.ts#L47

you can read more about timeouts here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#event-timeout

Whatever timeout setting you are using is too low for the server to respond.
Default Agent has timeout options in milliseconds, probably there is a way to configure that in this node module as well.
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#new-agentoptions
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-js/blob/558b3b4f6a5fd1e94c1579bd894cb0ce5e126368/packages/core/src/impl/node/NodeHttpTransport.ts#L62

Answer (score 0):

Checkout whether you have `new InfluxDB({})` under certain function, every time call that function would `new InfluxDB({})`, it may beyond `InfluxDB`'s capacity.
such as:

```
import ... from ...

class DB {
  static write_to_DB (data) {
    const writeclient = new InfluxDB({ url, token }).getWriteApi(org, bucket)   //wrong
    ....
  }
}
```

```
import ... from ...

const writeclient = new InfluxDB({ url, token }).getWriteApi(org, bucket)   //right

class DB {
  static write_to_DB (data) {
    ....
  }
}
```